# JavaScript - How to count an arbitrary number of clicks on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made a simple javascript application, for calculating the reaction time based on the speed in which a div is clicked. It's working pretty well. But i whish to count an arbitrary series of click (for examples, the first 10 clicks), and, afterwards, calculating the average of reaction time in these range of clicks.
Thanks for the help:

Comment: can you make question more clear. are you trying to calculate time elapse between these click as a average time ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply do:

```
var totalClicks = 0
```

In some <head> code

Then in the function that is called when it is clicked

```
totalClicks += 1;
if (totalClicks > 10) {
    doOtherStuff()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want the average of the time between each click for 10 clicks in total. To do this, you could add a timestamp to an array each time the button is clicked.

```
var clickTimestamps = [];

// Following code needs to be in the function you call when the button is clicked.
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
clickTimestamps.push(timestamp);

if (clickTimestamps.length > 10) {
   //calculate the average
}
```

The `new Date().getTime()` method returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01.

Answer (score 0):

for each and every click update the count value in the button tag.

Ex:

```js
function updateCount(){
 var oldClicks=parseInt($("#counter").attr("data-clicks"))
$("#counter").attr("data-clicks",oldClicks+1)
alert($("#counter").attr("data-clicks"))
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='counter' data-clicks='0' onclick='updateCount()'>counts</button>
```